# Отобразить время в формате hh:mm:ss указав количество секунд

Tags: php, время

Подскажите пожалуйста функцию на php. Необходимо отобразить время в формате hh:mm:ss указав количество секунд. Например указав 100 функция должна вывести 00:01:40.

И наоборот если есть такая возможность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function timeBySeconds($time) {
 return date_format(new DateTime('@'.$time),'H:i:s');
}

print timeBySeconds(100);
```

Может дать не более 24 часов, т.к. иначе увеличится номер дня, который мы не выводим. `DateTime` конструирует объект "дата", с параметром `@nnn` принимает nnn как количество секунд с 1 января 1970 года во временной зоне UTC.